# SQL Query for Dynamics CRM Entity records based on FormID

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, crm

I cannot seem to find the relationship between an entity's record and the entity's form used to create it.

my organization has a entity with two forms and we are looking to distinguish the records between the two forms in an SSRS report.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot find because there isn't a relationship between the record and the form used to create it.

If you want to try to differentiate, try to set a specific value in a custom field when the form create the record (by JavaScript for example) but is not 100% accurate (an expert use can change the value of that field or can be simulated when the record is created by the API)

let's say that using this way should be enough for your requirements.

Comment: Okay, I will try adding another custom field on one of the forms, then set a specific value,  thanks very much